# How a pointer to structure can be used before the structure is defined?

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-management, struct

I am having a hard time understanding how this code is working . I always thought before using pointer to a structure , it should be defined. In the below example why compiler doesn't complain about struct LL* Next ?

```
typedef struct LL
{
    int value;
    **struct LL* Next;**
}Node;

Node* temp;
```

Comment: Not very sure what you want to ask. Are you asking why `struct LL* Next;` is not an error?

Comment: The code you showed doesn't use any uninitialized pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code,

```
 struct LL* Next;
```

is allowed as a member inside the `struct LL` definition itself and does not throw any error, because, at that point, compiler need not know about the definition of the structure itself. It just needs to allocate a pointer to the structure, and so it can.

Later, while using a variable of the `struct` type, you have to allocate memory for the pointee and assign that memory to the pointer before any further usage.

Comment: You cannot answer this question without using the term *incomplete type*.

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to use an incomplete type (lacking sufficient information to determine the size of objects of that type) in a struct definition. When you write `struct LL* Next;` in the definition of `struct LL`, `LL` has already been declared as a struct, so no errors are thrown.

In fact, N1570 has provided some examples about this:

> 10 EXAMPLE 1 This mechanism allows declaration of a self-referential
>   structure.
>
> ```
>       struct tnode {
>             int count;
>             struct tnode *left, *right;
>       };
> ```
>
> specifies a structure that contains an integer and two pointers to
>   objects of the same type. ......
>
> 11 The following alternative formulation uses the typedef mechanism:
>
> ```
>       typedef struct tnode TNODE;
>       struct tnode {
>             int count;
>             TNODE *left, *right;
>       };
>       TNODE s, *sp;
> ```

Answer (score -1):

"Variables should always be initialized" is a rule of thumb.  It's not a great rule, and sometimes (like in your example), it must be violated, at least temporarily.  Uninitialized data (*garbage*) does not cause problems on its own.

Some programmers will religiously initialize their variables like this.

```
int i = 0;
Node * foo = NULL;
```

Nothing forces you to do that.  It's just programmers doing unnecessary things.

Initializing your pointers to something meaningful before dereferencing them *is* important though.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct LL
{
    int value;
    struct LL* next;
}Node;

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    Node * A; // OK.  A points at garbage.
    Node * B; // OK.  B points at garbage.
    B = A; // Dumb, but OK.  B now points at the same garbage as A.
    B = A->next; // ERROR.  You can't dereference garbage.
    A = malloc (sizeof(Node)); // A is no longer points at garbage.  The newly created A->value and A->Next are garbage though.
    B = A->next; // Dumb, but OK.  B now points at the same garbage as A->Next.
    B->value = 200; // ERROR.  B is garbage, you can't dereference garbage.
    A->value = 100; // OK.  A->value was garbage, but is now 100.

    // *********************************

    // Enough academic examples.  Let's finish making the linked list.
    A->next = malloc(sizeof(Node)); // OK. A->value no longer points at garbage.
    B = A->next; // OK.  B now points at the second node in the list.
    B->value = 200; // OK.  B->value was garbage, is now 200.
    B->next = NULL; // OK.  B->Next was garbage, is now NULL.

    printf("A: %#x, value: %d, next: %#x\n", A, A->value, A->next);
    printf("B: %#x, value: %d, next: %#x\n", B, B->value, B->next);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Node * A; Node * B; B = A;` is UB.

Comment: It's not a language lawyer question.